# How to Install Apache , MySQL and PHP on AIX 7.1

Tags: mysql, php, apache-2.2, aix, open-source

i want to install following open source software on AIX 7.1

**Apache 2.2.19**

PHP 5.2.6

MySQL - 5.0.67

please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Get the source and compile by yourself. I can access the [oss4aix.org](http://www.perzl.org/aix/) before but for the latest version of AIX (7.1), it requires the username and password.

Comment: ftp://www.oss4aix.org/latest/aix71/ seems to work fine.